# what is the difference between a redox reaction and an ionic bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, ionic-compounds

I am new into chemistry... 
I'd like to know what the difference is between an ionic bond: which involves a bond with an electron transfert, and a redox reaction; which seems to be exactly the same to me.

Thanks

Comment: Redox reaction and$\,\ldots$ ionic ***bond***?!

Comment: I know that one is a reaction and one is a bond, if that is the point you are trying to make. But at the end they both seem to do the same: transfert an electron. So could we say that redox reactions creates ionic bonds?

Comment: A redox reaction is where one compound/molecule  is reduced and the other oxidized , one gains electrons and the other loses electrons . An ionic bond is the force of attraction between two oppositely charged ions in which electrons are shared between the ions and the net charge is balanced.

Comment: In short, redox reactions may or may not create ionic bonds. There are examples of redox reactions which actually **destroy** ionic bonds, and others that have no relation to anything ionic whatsoever.

Comment: I know that this is how an ionic bond is first presented to beginners, but you should not think of ionic bonds as bonds involving electron transfers. Ionic bonds are merely "electrostatic attractions between oppositely charged ions". Now in the case of $\ce{NaCl}$, these oppositely charged ions are $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$, and these are obtained from neutral $\ce{Na}$ and $\ce{Cl}$ by transfer of one electron from $\ce{Na}$ to $\ce{Cl}$. **However, the electron transfer is not part of the formation of the ionic bond.**

Comment: The ionic bond **only** has to deal with the positively and negatively charged species. Where those positively and negatively charged species come from is *not* relevant to the formation of the ionic bond. For example, I could mix $\ce{AgNO3}$ and $\ce{NaCl}$, which causes $\ce{AgCl}$ to precipitate out - you could say there is an ionic bond between $\ce{Ag+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$. However, this ionic bond was **not** formed by electron transfer from $\ce{Ag}$ to $\ce{Cl}$.

Comment: @orthocresol Perfect explanation, that clears it up for me. _/me wonders why we can't award bounties on comments_

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An ionic bond is formed by electrostatic attraction of electrons between one atom and the other whereas in redox reactions the electrons are transferred from one atom to the other. Hope this helps.

Comment: But... the electrons of both atoms are negatively charged, so surely they should electrostatically *repel* each other?

Comment: "$\ldots\,$electrostatic attraction of *electrons*$\,\ldots$" -- Huh? And BTW, this seems like an attempt at providing the definitions, not similarities or differences. Not much of an answer.